# how to give permission to user or app to access /dev/ttyS0 without switching to sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am writing a python app which access the /dev/ttyS0. When the script runs it give permission denied for accessing /dev/ttyS0.

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyS0'

I tried modifying permissions but I still get the error. I am running this on Ubuntu 22.04 and python3. The script works if I switch to sudo su, but do not want to run as su

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  1 20:35 /dev/ttyS0 -> /dev/pts/4
```

I also tried adding user to to root group

```
getent group 0
root:x:0:tk
```

What else am I missing?

Python script

```
import serial    
ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyS0',
        baudrate=115200,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,
    )
    
    ser.isOpen()
```

Comment: There is any reason why you can run the python script using root?  also if you want to hide the sudo you can use an alias to hide the sudo execution and remove the password requirement to the specific script. Be careful with this approach because any one that can modify the python script can  modify the scrip to run any command as root.

Comment: @Roid my requirement is a user will log into linux and then used the app. the app in turn  will call /dev/ttyS0. the app listens to /dev/ttyS0 to receive informan from serial port. Please suggest what would be the best way to manage permission. I do prefer user of the application to access to sudo permissions

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu, serial devices are owned by the `dialout` group. Just make your user a member of the `dialup` group (`usermod -a -G dialup <username>`), log out and log back in, and you should be able to access serial devices without requiring elevated privileges. **However**: It is unusual to see that `/dev/ttyS0` is a symlink to a pty device; this may impact permissions; if that `ls` output is accurate, you'll want to look at the permissions on `/dev/pts/4` (or run `ls -lL /dev/ttyS0`).

Comment: @larsks I have added user to dialup and restarted system but still getting the error
`groups tk
tk : tk root tty dialout sudo vboxsf`
the `/dev/ttyS0` is symlink might be because currently i am simulating serial port communication using
 `socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0 pty,link=/dev/ttyS1,raw,echo=0`
 I ran `ls -lL /dev/ttyS0`  `crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Jan  2 12:09 /dev/ttyS0` anything else I am missing?

Comment: @kumar have you tried reading `man socat`? You need to look for user/group/mode options.

Answer (score 1):

You've looked onto the *symlink* permissions, while you needed to see the target ones. Those will be "`0660 root:dialout`". Putting a user into `dialout` group will allow them access **all** TTY devices on the system.

That might be way too much, depending on your needs and security requirements. If you want to precisely target exactly `/dev/ttyS0`, you need to add your own *udev rules* which will assign needed permissions to that device, and not use defaults. The existing machine defining default permissions is in `/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules`:

```
...
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="tty", GROUP="tty", MODE="0666"
KERNEL=="tty[A-Z]*[0-9]|ttymxc[0-9]*|pppox[0-9]*|ircomm[0-9]*|noz[0-9]*|rfcomm[0-9]*", GROUP="dialout"
...
```

You may create a dedicated group and a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-your-name.rules` with the following line:

```
KERNEL=="ttyS0", GROUP="dedicated-group", MODE="0666"
```

That will setup custom permissions on that device. I am too lazy to test this thoroughly, but this is the supposed way to do things.

Be careful. Different devices may receive this name, depending on random races during initialization. It is not safe to rely on `ttyS0` always being the correct device. Much safer is to refer to other attributes, like serial number, PCI bus address and so on.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant as udev doesn't control pseudo-ttys. You should notice that in the OP case /dev/ttyS0 is a link to /dev/pts/4.

Comment: @nikita I still think your suggestion will be used when I go to actuall implementation when the device is connected the system. any suggestions on how to refer to the device when RS232 cable is connect to the system?